# Can I remotely control a Virtualbox using vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I know vagrant is giving `vagrant connect` and `vagrant share` feature to connect a remote Vagrant box. My boxes are on remote machine and I can not install vagrant on that host machine. Is there any plugin or workaround so that we can remotely control virtual boxes using vagrant without installing it in host?

Comment: Vagrant boxes are really just virtual machines, so if you expose them, you should be able to ssh into them from a remote host, no?

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose they are virtual machines but typically connected to a private network with the host so would not be exposed. assuming they were on a public network, the port would also not be default ssh. Vern Burton answered this well.

Answer (score 1):

If those boxes aren't instantiated by Vagrant, then Vagrant doesn't know about them.  It really only understands Vagrantfile configurations.

Vagrant is largely a wrapper around VBoxManage which has no ability to execute its commands against a remote host.

If you are using NAT/ NAT Service however, you should be able to get to them as if they are part of your local network, but managing them is a no.  You would need to install the extension pack on the VirtualBox host and enable the Web API included in the extension pack and use RemoteBox to manage it.

Source: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html
Source: http://remotebox.knobgoblin.org.uk/documentation.cgi

You will not be able to use vagrant commands at this point, but you would be required to use standard SSH commands and SSH keys.

Vagrant Share/Connect require Vagrant and Atlas so can't be used without it.

Comment: Thanks @Vern for a nice answer. let me explore your links

Answer (score 0):

If vagrant is only a wrapper around `VBoxManage`, then you should be able to create your own `VBoxManage` which would be a script that runs SSH, then `VBoxManage` on the remote.

There might be some other jiggery-pokery to setup, maybe sudo, maybe networking things, but if the original assumption holds it should be doable.

Edit: actually, vagrant wants to SSH to the VM as part of startup, so you'll have to figure out a way to hook in there too, and that might be a bit harder.